# Some sort of design pattern for handling nil and empty Activerecord relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null, selection

I am constantly checking for ".nil?" , ".empty?"  or ".present?"  in my controllers. Because otherwise Rails will complain with a error 500 when it has to work with an empty ActiveRecord Relation. As I am coding it again and again I feel that I do something very wrong.

I keep asking myself why I have to check my ActiveRecord relation all the time as it is quit common for a database selection that it is empty.

Is there some sort of design pattern that i can use to get rid of this kind of checks (if/else) and make my controllers cleaner and more readable?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you give an illustrative example?

Comment: Null Object patterns... Or something like http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none

Comment: compact gets rid of nil objects in an array http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/compact

Comment: plus one for Null Object pattern - http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/